css module parse failed nextjs 14
I created a new nextjs app using npx create-next-app@latest.
when I run npm run dev I get following error:
./src/app/globals.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
> @tailwind base;
| @tailwind components;
| @tailwind utilities;

Device and env details:
os: windows 11,
node: v18.20.3,
npm: 10.7.0
I create a new nextjs application from scratch.

I've cloned your repo and ran it on my end and it works perfectly. I also did some digging online and found that this issue is usually caused by using the next-transpile-modules package but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Really weird

could it be windows specific issue? I tried installing nextjs without taiwind it still shows same error.

Heads up for anyone having same issue:-
It was my system specific issue. It was working on MacOS and other people windows.
I had to reset my windows in order to fix it.
